# How to mock the Observable return angular service?

Tags: angular, observable, karma-runner

`this.variable = this.service.getMydata();`

The above service is returning Observable and for the variable I have subscribed as below.

`this.variable.subscribe(data => { My logic here});`

How would right unit test for this in angular 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const mockResponse = {
  // ...
};

spyOn(service, 'getMydata').and.returnValue(of(mockResponse));
```

Comment: I could not get the response in subscribe as data

Answer (score 0):

Mock the service and the method to return observable

```
    const mockService = {
       getMydata: {
          return of(<Response>)
       }
    }

   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       declarations: [...],
       providers: [{provide: Service, useValue: mockService}]
   })
```